# ASP.NET MVC : view and controller problem when letting the view upload an image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, view, controller

Solved by using a view model that has `HttpPostedFileBase` property bound to the view, so that the form only requires a single post method to upload the image and then add the entity to the database.

Here is the form tag:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Lessons", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

and the view control bound to the view model property (happens by default if the names match, in my case the property is `HttpPostedFileBase` file:

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

This is far easier than the path I was on below, trying to have two different post actions for a single view (which should be possible from everything I read, but I think my problem was trying to have a form within a form):

My controller for Lesson has two post methods that can be called:

The first is to create a new Lesson:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Lesson lesson)//, WebImage Photo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && Request.Form["Create"]!=null) 
            //Request.Form check because the image file function is calling back to this handler
            //Once that is sorted out the check can be removed and simply use ModelState.IsValid
        {
            db.Lessons.Add(lesson);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.DivID = new SelectList(db.Divisions, "ID", "DivName", lesson.DivID);
        ViewBag.ProjectID = new SelectList(db.Projectinformations, "ID", "Code", lesson.ProjectID);
        ViewBag.PeopleID = new SelectList(db.Peoples, "ID", "Firstname", lesson.PeopleID);
        return View(lesson);
    }
```

On the page this is the form (shortened) with the submit button that calls the controller.Create() action:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 //. . . for each Lesson property there is a form group with @Html Label
 //@Html.EditorFor, etc. and then at the bottom is this:

        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" name="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

The image path field is part of the main form, and I left the generated code for it's text box etc.  This is the part of the form where I'm trying to insert an image upload that calls a different controller action:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <form action="UploadImage" name="ImageFileForm" id="imageForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="file" />
                <input type="submit" value="OK" name="OK" />
            </form>
        </div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Image, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the contoller action for UploadImage

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string imagePath ="";
        if (file != null)
        {
            var newFileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            imagePath = @"LessonsLearnedImages\" + newFileName;
            file.SaveAs(@"~\" + imagePath);
        }
        ViewBag.DivID = new SelectList(db.Divisions, "ID", "DivName", lesson.DivID);
        ViewBag.ProjectID = new SelectList(db.Projectinformations, "ID", "Code", lesson.ProjectID);
        ViewBag.MOAPeopleID = new SelectList(db.MOApeoples, "ID", "Firstname", lesson.MOAPeopleID);
        ViewBag.Image = imagePath;
        return View();
    }
```

When I press the ImageUpload button however, the controller Create (form default) function gets called.  I can potentially use the Create action in the controller to do everything with a Request.Form check, but this has failed for me when adding a HttpPostedFileBase parameter to it.

Comment: You have two post methods? Can you include the other one in the question?

Comment: @OJRaqueño I added that second Post, which is what was created when I added the controller.  I"m now trying some javascript to handle it because the only way I can get the photo is with the WebImage.GetImageFromRequest() method which does not work in the controller when I called the controller with Url.Action.

Comment: To help the framework identify which controller method it should execute, create a clone of your `Create` method and rename it to `Upload` (`public async Task<ActionResult> Upload`) and then explicitly reference it in the action attribute of your form (`form action="Upload"`).

Comment: @OJRaqueño I have done that, and found that the object I need to use (obtained by WebImage.GetImageFromRequest() does not work once the scope has left the page.  So I think I need to have a model property that can contain that element, but not sure how to get it to bind directly without using some javascript.

Comment: I think that this question is not really addressing my problem, but just exposes my lack of knowledge when it comes to client side functionality in the MVC and EF world.  But just asking it always helps me to progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With image upload there are two things that you need to save. The first part is saving the actual image, eg. saving onto a folder on your computer. The second part is saving info about the image, eg. saving its full path in a database. Doing both parts are essential so that you can retrieve the image later.

One way to capture images (or uploaded files in general) is by using `HttpPostedFileBase` as the type of parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(HttpPostedFileBase myFile)
{
    // myFile contains several properties which you need to be able to save the file
}
```

The `myFile` parameter has several properties that you need for saving. Examples are the path from which you are uploading the image and the actual image content which you can extract as a `byte[]`.

The corresponding form on the web page, trimmed down to the essential bits, would be:

```
<form action="Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="Click me to upload" />
</form>
```

You need to make sure the following line up so that the correct controller action gets called:

- The method of the form should match the verb of the controller method (`post` in the form corresponding to `HttpPost` in the controller)
- The action of the form should match the name of the controller method (`Upload` in this case)
- The name of the input should match the name of the controller method's parameter (`myFile` in this case)

You also need to make sure that the enctype is `multipart/form-data` in order for the `myFile` parameter to actually have a value. If not, you may execute the correct controller method, but the parameter may be null.

After all of that, you should have a proper `myFile` parameter whose properties you can use to save. For example, after saving the image, you can store its full path in an `ImagePath` column in your `Lessons` table.

As you mentioned, the image (and anything else for that matter) gets lost once the controller method finishes executing. But that's okay, because we already have the image and image path saved in persistent storage. To retrieve the image at a later time, you can just look at the associated lesson. For example, assuming you have a `Model` object that corresponds to a lesson that you got from the database, displaying the image could look like this:

```
<img src="@Model.ImagePath" />
```

**EDIT**

It seems that you want to save multiple fields on the create page in one go, with the image file only being one of the fields. In that case, only a single method is needed on the controller and only a single form element is needed on the page.

To capture the file, add the `HttpPostedFileBase` as a property in your lesson view model, for example:

```
public class Lesson
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The piece that is failing for me is getting the post for this action execute the correct controller method.  I'll try again however.  By the way, my index page shows the lessons and images that get created through a WPF desktop app that I created.  Trying to reproduce that app now as an MVC .net app is such a different approach.

Comment: In the controller I can save the image path and image to the webroot.  But how do I then pass back the new image path parameter to the lesson object in the create page from the controller?  IE, the imagepath is only one of the Lesson fields that I'm trying to set, and trying to get it to happen on one page.  So can the controller affect the Lesson as it exists on the page?  IE, the instance the controller sees is tightly bound to the instance the page has?

Comment: Ok, I still get the UploadFile form action calling the main controller Create action.  I'm editing my post to better clarify what two submit actions I have on the page and the controller methods they (should) point to.

Comment: WPF and MVC is really different, in that things are lost by default. The only way for the objects in your controller to be accessible in the page is if you return them, such as in `return View(yourModel)` or placing them in things such as the `ViewBag`. And the only way for the objects in your page to be accessible in your controller is to pass them along explicitly, eg. as parameter/s in your controller actions.

Comment: I edited my question to show how I've attempted to use a controller action, but with two post methods it seems that I cannot get the UploadImage controller method to be called, the default form post method (Create) always gets called.

Comment: It seems that you want to save multiple fields on the create page in one go, with the image file only being one of the fields. In this case, only a single method is needed on the controller and only a single `form` element is needed on the page. If you include the `HttpPostedFileBase` as a parameter in your existing `Create` method in the controller, I believe it should still be able to capture the image you are trying to upload.

Comment: Either that or add it as a property to your `Lesson` class (eg. `public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }`)

Comment: This is what I had to do . . . add that property to my view model, bind it to the view, and just have one post method that saves the file and the new path into the database.  Thanks for your time!  If you edit your answer I'll accept it and clarify my implementation in the question.